# Right way to delete and then reindex ES documents

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have a python3 script that attempts to reindex certain documents in an existing ElasticSearch index. I can't update the documents because I'm changing from an autogenerated id to an explicitly assigned id.

I'm currently attempting to do this by deleting existing documents using `delete_by_query` and then indexing once the delete is complete:

```
self.elasticsearch.delete_by_query(
                index='%s_*' % base_index_name,
                doc_type='type_a',
                conflicts='proceed',
                wait_for_completion=True,
                refresh=True,
                body={}
            )
```

However, the index is massive, and so the delete can take several hours to finish. I'm currently getting a `ReadTimeoutError`, which is causing the script to crash:

```
WARNING:elasticsearch:Connection <Urllib3HttpConnection: X> has failed for 2 times in a row, putting on 120 second timeout.
WARNING:elasticsearch:POST X:9200/base_index_name_*/type_a/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=true&refresh=true [status:N/A request:140.117s]
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='X', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=140)
```

Is my approach correct? If so, how can I make my script wait long enough for the `delete_by_query` to complete? There are 2 timeout parameters that can be passed to `delete_by_query` - `search_timeout` and `timeout`, but `search_timeout` defaults to no timeout (which is I think what I want), and `timeout` doesn't seem to do what I want. Is there some other parameter I can pass to `delete_by_query` to make it wait as long as it takes for the delete to finish? Or do I need to make my script wait some other way?

Or is there some better way to do this using the ElasticSearch API?

Comment: What version of ES are you using? Newer versions have a reindex feature in the API, but you'll have to manage it using CURL requests...the Python driver didn't support it last I checked. Still much faster than delete + reindex.

Comment: Version 5.2.1. I'm using spark to do the actual indexing, so I'm not sure that I'd be able to use that feature. Also, it looks like the reindex API uses existing documents in another index and moves them to a new index (with the possibility of providing a script that modifies the document). I don't think that would work for me because the changes to the documents are non-trivial and require external resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `wait_for_completion` to `False`. In this case you'll get `task` details and will be able to track task progress using corresponding API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-task-api

Comment: Is there a way to get the task information back via the elasticsearch python API? I could get it by using `requests` but would prefer to use the ES API if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain more in the form of codebase explained by [Random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670928/random) for the newbee in ES/python like me:

```
ES = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])
query = {'query': {'match_all': dict()}}  
task_id = ES.delete_by_query(index='index_name', doc_type='sample_doc',  wait_for_completion=False, body=query, ignore=[400, 404])
response_task = ES.tasks.get(task_id) # check if the task is completed
isCompleted = response_task["completed"] # if complete key is true it means task is completed
```

One can write custom definition to check if the task is completed in some interval using while loop.

I have used python 3.x and ElasticSearch 6.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'request_timeout' global param. This will reset the Connections timeout settings, as mentioned [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.1/api.html#timeout)

For example -

```
es.delete_by_query(index=<index_name>, body=<query>,request_timeout=300)
```

Or set it at connection level, for example

```
es = Elasticsearch(**(get_es_connection_parms()),timeout=60)
```