# AWS Elasticsearch - Delete_by_query, how to find task id so can continue with code when delete is done, and when to do wait_for _completion

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS Lambda to do a delete_by_query on an Elasticsearch index so I get rid of everything older than 7 days. That works, but I noticed that the count of the documents is the same before and after, so if I were to run a query in Elasticsearch I may not get correct results until the delete_by_query is completed.

I found this post ([python 3.x - Right way to delete and then reindex ES documents - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371047/right-way-to-delete-and-then-reindex-es-documents)) that states that it is "best to  set wait_for_completion to False. In this case you'll get task details and will be able to track task progress."  For one, I haven't found anything that states why this is the case, unless your delete takes 4 hours like that example.

I found code to determine if the delete_by_query is still running at this wonderful site [here](https://cinhtau.net/pages/elastic/elasticsearch/delete/) and tried:

`es_client.tasks(detailed=True,actions="*/delete/byquery")`

However, I'm getting the message that
`'TasksClient' object is not callable.`

I am not entirely sure if that is true or not , or if my syntax is incorrect and thus that is why it is not working.  It doesn't make sense that I can't programmatically query Tasks with python if I can do it in the console and with curl.

If it is not good to set wait_for_completion to False, and I can't query this with Python, how am I to programmatically get any information about the task or an understanding as to whether I can go ahead with the analytical queries or whatever else I want to do that depends on this task being done?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not entirely sure why you are getting that error, so I can't help with that in particular. But, I noticed that the python elasticsearch documentation on how to get the task id from the delete_by_query when wait_for_completion is set to false isn't very clear, so I'm going to provide this in case it helps.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    
es = Elasticsearch()

response = es.delete_by_query(index=someIndex, body=someQuery, wait_for_completion=False)

# get task id
print(response['task'])
```

Hope that helps!